# How to construct a string by joining characters efficiently?

Tags: python, string

I have a long string `s1`, and a list of positions of characters `lst = [...]` in this string. I want to construct a string `s2` which contains only the characters of `s1` in the positions given by `lst`. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
newstring = "".join(s1[i] for i in lst)
```

If you don't absolutely *know* that `s1` won't have any indexes that are too long, do this:

```
newstring = "".join(s1[i:i+1] for i in lst)
```

It's slower, but no index errors.

**Edit:** It has been brought to my attention that using a list comprehension rather than a generator expression in `"".join(...)` is more efficient, so to do that, just add brackets:

```
newstring = "".join([s1[i] for i in lst])
```

Comment: This will raise an index error if there was an index greater than the string's length . Also it's not very efficient to use a generator expression within `join()`.

Comment: `lst` is the position of the characters in `s1`, by that definition it can't be out of it's bounds

Comment: @Kasramvd of course, it is up to the OP to use input data that makes sense/sanitize it beforehand. OP did not mention that his list might not make sense. This solution is fine and can be adjusted easily.

Comment: @Kasramvd: Yeah, I added a second solution.  It's probably slower than yours, but I don't want to steal solutions from other people. ;)

Comment: @timgeb Yes and it would be perfect if used list comprehension instead of generator expression.

Comment: @Kasramvd: I added that, too.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> s = '0123456789'
>>> lst = [0, 3, 6, 8]
>>> ''.join(itemgetter(*lst)(s))
'0368'
```

Since you asked for efficiency, this should be a little faster than joining the generator:

```
In [6]: timeit ''.join(s[i] for i in lst)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 µs per loop

In [7]: timeit ''.join(itemgetter(*lst)(s))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 430 ns per loop
```

edit: I also think the code should not jump through hoops for lists that don't make sense. If there are nonsensical indexes in the list you want your code to raise an `IndexError` and then recover from there.

Comment: You start with "Alternatively, ...". Alternatively _to what_?

Comment: Should also compare with `timeit ''.join([s[i] for i in lst])`. I did it and I get almost no difference to using `itemgetter` (`itemgetter` is still slightly faster though). I don't want to post my numbers because it depends on machine, etc.

Comment: I'm accepting `zondo`'s answer, because the time difference does not seem to be significant (see my previous comment) and I find it more readable.